# Is there a way in oracle sql developer to create multiple users at once

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a group of students that I want to grant student privilege's to a specific database set up in oracle. Is there a way to do this at once or I can only do it individually?

I have an excel spreadsheet with student numbers and here is the sql code I am using to add them individually so far

```
CREATE USER S56879 IDENTIFIED BY student
DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
QUOTA 100M ON users;

GRANT STUDENTROLE TO S56879;
```

Comment: Make sure each student has their own, unique password

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can import the Excel data into a table and then use dynamic SQL; something like:

```
begin
    for s in (select student_num from someTable) loop
        execute immediate 'CREATE USER ' || s.student_num || ' IDENTIFIED BY ...';
        execute immediate 'GRANT STUDENTROLE TO ' || s.student_num;
    end loop;
end;
```